# Web.config settings for multiple Nhibernate projects

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would love to create separate NHibernate projects for the various modules of my application(So I can maintain each independently).Each project will be self contained kinda(mappings,data, persistence manager etc)

I'm confused as to how I can reference these various projects in the main project(MVC5 web app).I'm thinking I have to create a named section for each project in the web.config file but not sure how to go about this.

Any ideas? Sample config settings? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a long drawn silence here and much searching, I finally figured what to do, which is basically:
Create the modules as separate projects(warehousing mappings for that module).
In the main project, while initialing Nhibernate do something like:

`NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();`

`configuration.AddAssembly("project1"); //the assembly that contains the .hbm files for project1`
`configuration.AddAssembly("project2"); //the assembly that contains the .hbm files for project2`